# dynamic route in nodejs using GET method in a form

Tags: node.js, forms, post, routes, get

I have a search box, in which I'm taking the user input using a form.
The form has a certain method and action.

```
 <form action="/public/search" method="GET">
```

In my routes files, I want to add a controller to this route, I don't know how to access this route in my routes file.
These are all the routes that I tried and didn't work.
Also, I do want it to be a GET request and not a POST request.

```
const router = require('express').Router();


router.get('/public/search', getSearch);
router.get('/public/search/:id', getSearch);
router.get('/public/search?search=/:id', getSearch);
```

Comment: Can you add the express-setup? e.g. how you set the router?

Comment: Done. mentioned in the question. @eol

Comment: It still needs some more details, how are you wiring up the router with the express app? Through `app.use(router)`?